# How do I disable root password login prompt when starting the terminal

Tags: command-line

I gave my friend my laptop. But he did something with it and now every time I open the terminal it ask for the root password for me to use it. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to go back to my home directory but I cant.

How do I solve this?

Comment: what is the output of `grep sudo .bashrc` and `grep sudo .bash_profile` ?

Comment: root@gerishom-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~# grep sudo .bashrc
root@gerishom-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~# grep sudo .bash_profile
grep: .bash_profile: No such file or directory

Comment: okay, it seems you open the terminal as root directly ...  please close the terminal and Press Alt+F2 and type `gnome-terminal` and enter. What happens? Does it open a normal non-root terminal ?

Comment: no it still opens the terminal as root